# onbeforeunload not triggered properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

I can't figure out why the script isn't working with the form.  Why doesn't the `$("form").submit(function()` call the form with id `form`? This script isn't even performing the `window.onbeforeunload` so I guess the script is faulty.  Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
<form id="formID" class="access_form" name="form" method="post" action="site.com">          
    <div class="row">
        <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
        <input class="txt_email" type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" class="btn_access"  value="Get Immediate Access" name="submit1" />
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var formHasChanged = false;
var submitted = false; 

$(document).on('change', 'form.confirm-navigation-form input, form.confirm-navigation-form
select, form.confirm-navigation-form textarea', function (e) { 
    formHasChanged = true; 
}); 

$(document).ready(function () { 
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) { 
        if (formHasChanged && !submitted) { 
            var message = "Please enter your email", e = e || window.event; 
            if (e) { 
                e.returnValue = message; 
            } 
            return message; 
        } 
    }
$("#formID").submit(function () { 
 submitted = true; 
});
});
```

Comment: The *Error Console* should give you any error in the script.

Answer (score 0):

just try this.The id of the form is form itself.So select the form like this using jQuery

```
$("#form").submit(function () {
  submitted = true;
});
```

OR

Or try giving another id for the form for example "formID".Then select using  that id like this.

```
$("#formID").submit(function () {
  submitted = true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I used $("#formID").submit(function(){ 
    submitted=true; 
    });  but no go... the script isn't working at all.  Shouldn't the script work even without being connected to the form?

Comment: Hmmmm... still doesn't work even after the revisions.  Ok, just so I've got what's supposed to happen, whether the trafficur clicks away from my site or doesn't fill in the email box and click submit, either way, they should get the warning window, right?

Comment: So, what I have now, is in the first post.